# Cmake: Add extra generated file

Tags: cmake, dependencies

I have a C file that is processed to generate two .h files. One of those headers is included in the c-file itself, another C file includes both.

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT header1.h header2.h
        COMMENT "Generating headers" 
        DEPENDS thecfile.c
        COMMAND ../mkheaders
        )

add_custom_target(generate_headers DEPENDS header1.h)
add_dependencies(rackmaster  generate_headers)
```

This works, but it ALWAYS generates the headers, instead of only when "thecfile.c" changes.

How do I modify this to create the proper dependencies?

Comment: Do your `mkheaders` program actually creates `header1.h` and `header2.h` files in the **build** directory? Exactly this is implied when you use **relative paths** in OUTPUT parameter: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html

Comment: Yeah I found out that the script is run from my buld directory. For now I pass it the source dir as an argument and the script will first CD there and generate them there. 
It would be neater to generate them into a "generated" directory like the "xxx_pio.h" files for RP2040 PIO programs. I'll figure that out once I get the dependencies right.